# Why didn't the CD come with a caddy by default?

Tags: storage, cd-rom

I've had plenty of scratched disks over the years, even scratched many myself when I was a kid. But it's my scratched copy of Call of Duty World at War for the PS3 that really makes me ask this question.

Disk caddies! They hold the disk in a protective case! Just put the caddy in the drive! No need to handle the disk! It prevents 99% of scratches!

When the CD first released back in the early 80's (or is it late 70's?) why did Sony and Philips even allow the disk itself to be "naked"? Why didn't they make a caddy mandatory?

Yes, all optical media has error correction. But stupid finds a way, so why not be EXTRA safe by mandating disk caddies?

Minidisk and UMD did this, why not CD? (And ultimately DVD and Bluray).

Comment: Apparently, early ones did, actually: <https://tedium.co/2021/03/12/cd-rom-caddy-history/>.

Comment: "To caddy or not to caddy?", https://cdrfaq.org/faq05.html#S5-9

Comment: Possibly because CDs (not necessarily CD-ROMs) were initially marketed as "indestructible".... one UK TV show even put jam on the *top side* and then put the jammy CD in a player to prove it, even though it proved nothing, in fact. Also, maybe cost was kept down but not having a caddy..?

Comment: The CD was intended as a medium for delivering music, and no CD audio player intended for playing music (that I am aware of) ever accepted a CD in a caddy -- because there was no need for it.

Comment: I had a Pioneer stereo that took 6 CD carts. So for car and home use, I used to have CDs mounted in a form a caddy. I don't think the Pioneer system ever really became mainstream as added complexity. For examples search 'Pioneer 6-Disc CD Changer Magazine / Cartridge'

Comment: Depending on the scratch depth, your Call of Duty World at War might be salvageable.  I've had great success by using simple toothpaste to gently buff out scuffs and scratches on various CD's over the years.  You basically use the toothpaste like a fine polishing compound (no water) and then rinse the residue and repeat until success.  If you haven't already tried, you might want to give it a go...

Comment: The initial version of blue ray came with a caddy but was removed later on. Fundamentally CD was meant to be a consumable and not a collectable. The majority of pop music is only played for a few dozens of times after all.

Comment: This isn't a computing question.  CDs were around in CD-A format long before they started to be used for computers as CD-ROM etc.  Also, compare with the likes of RCA Laserdisc, which also didn't have caddies.

Comment: *The majority of pop music...*  By legend, the specification for the CD was that it had to be of sufficient capacity to hold Beethoven's Ninth.

Comment: "Not a computer question"? Really? _Really?_ The millions of CD/DVD/Bluray-roms are not computer related?

Comment: Your question asks why CDs don't require caddies, and the answer is that the designers of **a medium they intended to be used for delivery of audio content** saw no need, since earlier, less robust audio media hadn't needed it (audio users were either accustomed to looking after recordings, or else didn't care). CD-ROMs came ~4 years later, CD-ROMs for games about ~8 years later, and the caddyless nature of the disc was already established.

Comment: Sure, it was originally audio only, but it quickly became ubiquitous in the world of computing once the CD-ROM standard was released.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> When the CD first released back in the early 80's (or is it late 70's?)

First shown 1981 in Berlin, introduced worldwide 1982.

> why did Sony and Philips even allow the disk itself to be "naked"?

To start with, it wasn't 'naked' but protected by a case.

> Why didn't they make a caddy mandatory?

Why should they?

- Neither LP nor Singles, which the CD was intended to replace, came with 'caddies'. Not even protective cases but paper/cardboard sleeves. People were quite aware how to handle those.
- In fact, CDs do need way less care than classic disks as their surface is not only more durable than vinyl. Plus error correction allowing even more abuse.
- Why making drives and even more each disk more expensive than it has to be?

In addition:

- Early data drives used with computers were (mostly) caddy based. After all, it isn't a big deal to spend a few bucks on caddies when the drive alone is close to 1000 USD - not counting the mandatory SCSI controller.
- Conversion of cheap tray drive designs was a major step in making drives affordable for non professional (aka home/game) users - that and the low cost Mitsumi interface.

> Yes, all optical media has error correction. But stupid finds a way, so why not be EXTRA safe by mandating disk caddies?

Why should all users pay a premium because a few are, as you call them, 'stupid'? Shouldn't that be up to the ones needing it?

In the end it is everyone's own decision if he buys a lower priced tray and handle disks with some care, or buy a more expensive caddy based drive and lots of caddies.

> Minidisk and UMD did this, why not CD?

Special media where a company controlled both ends - and for sure less successful than the CD :)

> And ultimately DVD and Bluray.

Both were designed with mandatory compatibility. Not only to allow creation of drives able to play multiple types, but more important to use the advantage of the existing production, packaging and logistics all the way to rack sizes in shops.

It pays to be not too different.

---

Personal Note:

I bught my first CD player ca. 1983. Player alone needed the space of a later desktop PC, despite being an audio-only device. Over the years I had next to all variations, caddy, tray or multi-disk cartridge. Still, in tose ~40 years of CD/DVD usage (*1) I had only a single CD I could no longer read: Disk#1 of [Wizardry 8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wizardry_8) - although the reason was quite clear: I broke it by stepping on :))

---

Comment: What I meant by "stupid finds a way" is Murphy's law. If it can happen, it probably will. Heck, even well cared disks will get some scratches!

Comment: However, I did suspect the cost angle is the primary reason. It's cheaper to ditch the caddy instead of pouring R&D into tuning the production of caddies to be as cheap as possible. Perhaps it's the case of engineers wanting to add something but the high brass in the company eventually ditched it. Still though, caddies would of saved many CD's, and ultimately DVD's and Bluray's due to the compatibility thing you expanded on.

Comment: @qwertykeyboard no-caddy can always be produced at lower cost as a-caddy, isn't it? :))

Comment: Yep! I'm a manufacturing nerd so stuff like cost reduction peeks my imagination!

Comment: I mean, in the 80s and most of the 90s if you did somehow scratch a music CD so bad it wouldn't play any more you just went out and spent another $12 to replace it. And that was **much** less likely than damaging a cassette or vinyl record. Heck, cassettes and LPs could get ruined just by listening to them! So people were already replacing damaged music media before the CD came out. After the CD came out the annual budget for replacing damaged music went **way** down.

Comment: s/chap/cheap/ ?

Comment: *caddies would of saved many CD* - and, I'm pretty sure, have further inflated the cost of the ~1000 audio CDs I own, none of which has been damaged through poor handling.

Comment: I want to second that thing about LP's and 45's. We were very used to carefully touching those on the sides, and were good at it. It felt completely natural to treat CD's the same way. I recall a friend saying about a CD "you could serve a slice of pizza on this still play it" -- while carefully holding it by the edges.

Comment: KIds today and their 'streaming' services, eh?  ;-)